# C++ Including Files

Tags: c++, file, include

A problem I'm having is when using a class (one header, one cpp file), I am wondering when including a file in the header file that is also needed in the source file of the class what should I do? I'll give an example

header.h (file)

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "some_other_header.h"

class class_name
{
    public:
        LRESULT CALLBACK FUNC(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
    private:
}
```

source.cpp (file)

```
#include "header.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
```

As you know LRESULT Is part of the  library and it does not need to be included in "source.cpp" because it's included in the "header.h" file. The problem is if I include "header.h" in any other file I wouldn't have to include  either because it's already in "header.h" this is a bit confusing, it's kind of hard to explain but I want to completely avoid any errors this may bring.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762699/which-is-the-correct-way-to-use-a-header-file-in-c

Comment: Use the [`#pragma once` preprocessor directive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once) or comparable...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is the correct way to use a header file in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762699/which-is-the-correct-way-to-use-a-header-file-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary. `#include` directive copies the content of file verbatim in the place of `#include`. So any file included in a file will be included down. In your example, you have `Windows.h>`, `"some_other_header.h` and `header.h` all included in your .cpp file (as well as any header included by `Windows.h` and `some_other_header.h`).

It is often a good practice to include them anyway, so that you don't depend on some header 10 files above, but it is usually omitted within header-source pair. It's not really resonable to copy the headers if you need them both for function declaration and definition.

---

On another side, you should add a header guard because of the mechanism mentioned above. Without a guard, you may encounter double definition problems, when a header get's included from different sources. If you are going to use this header in more than one file, they are a necessity, and good practice otherwise.

Standard header guard looks like this:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H //or any other name, typically it's filename or filename with path
#define HEADER_H 
//your header here
#endif
```

Most compilers also support non-standard pragma directiveL

```
#pragma once
//your header here
```

Answer (score 0):

The good practice is too keep all the files *self-sufficient*. That is each file should explicitly include headers declaring each symbol that is used in this file. Keeping complete list of includes in each file may seem like a waste of time however not following this rule leads to fragile codebases where modifying includes in one file may trigger a tsunami of broken declarations throughout entire project and drastic time losses.

Comment: Are you saying I should just include the files individually to each file? If so thanks, that's what I was thinking to do.

Answer (score -1):

It's safe to not include the header in your `.cpp` file as long as it's included elsewhere. `#include` is almost the same as simply cutting and pasting the file's contents in where the directive is, so after preprocessing, you end up with one huge file that contains everything that got included. As long as it ends up in there before anything that uses its contents, you're good.

I'd suggest, though, that if you use stuff from `windows.h` in some way that's independent of `header.h`, you include the header anyway, so you know for certain that you will *always* end up including the header you need. Any self-respecting library header file, including `windows.h`, is safe to `#include` twice -- it keeps itself from being re-included in the same translation unit, whether via include guards or via `#pragma once`. And if `header.h` can one day change to not need `windows.h`, you want to be able to make that change without causing a bunch of errors.